# Wordpress: Create static permalink in htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, permalinks

I want to put a static permalink in the `.htaccess` file. For example when I go to the http://www.example-page.com/testsite  the server redirect to this http://www.example-page.com/wp-admin/example.php?test=data

My problem is that I didn't want to destroy the permalink structure of the WordPress blog.

My `.htaccess` file code looks like as follows:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this rule after `RewriteBase /`

```
RewriteRule ^testsite$ /wp-admin/example.php?test=data [R=301,L]
```

It will intercept only the specified URI and redirect it.
Other WP's permalinks should work as usual.

Comment: it works. But can i redirect to the page without changing the url?

Comment: Do you mean "rewrite" instead of "redirect"? If so, just remove `R=301` flag.

Comment: Make sure you have specified correct path to `/wp-admin/example.php?test=data`